# Eloquent relationship issue : belongsTo

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm new with Laravel.

I have these Models :

- Modality,
- ReportsGroup,
- Report,
- User

Basically, I'm trying to build some relationship :

**- A ReportsGroup belongs to a Modality,**

**- A Modality has many ReportsGroups,**

**- A ReportsGroup has many Reports,**

**- A Report belongs to a ReportsGroup,**

**- A Report has one User,**

**- A User has many Reports.**

(the lines in bold are the relationship I cannot reach...)

MODEL :

```
Modality.php

    namespace App;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class Modality extends Model
    {
        public function reportGroups()
        {
          $this->hasMany(ReportsGroup::class);
        }
    }
```

ReportsGroup.php :

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ReportsGroup extends Model
{
  public function modality()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo(Modality::class);
  }
  public function reports()
  {
    return $this->hasMany(Report::class);
  }
}
```

Report.php

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Report extends Model
{
    public function author()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'author_id');
    }
    public function reportsGroup()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo(ReportsGroup::class, 'reportsGroup_id');
    }
}
```

MIGRATIONS :

Table modalities :

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('modalities', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('title')->nullable();
            $table->text('description')->nullable();
            $table->boolean('is_active')->default(true);
            $table->boolean('is_free')->default(true);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Table reportsGroups :

```
public function up()
{
  Schema::create('reports_groups', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->id();
      $table->unsignedBigInteger('modality_id');
      $table->string('title');
      $table->text('description')->nullable();
      $table->timestamps();
  });
}
```

Table reports

```
  public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('reports', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('reportsGroup_id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->text('indication')->nullable();
            $table->text('technique')->nullable();
            $table->text('conclusion')->nullable();
            $table->text('recommandations')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('author_id');
            $table->boolean('is_visible')->defaut(true);
            $table->boolean('is_free')->default(true);
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->index('reportsGroup_id');
            $table->index('author_id');
        });
    }
```

Table users :

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

As I wrote, the only relationship that seems to work is the fact that a ReportsGrouop belongs to a Modality...

It's been days I am stuck with this issue...

Please help!
Thanks,

Nicolas

Comment: Can you also please post your query for proper assistance?

Comment: Right now I'm testing with Tinker ! So I'm just trying to check with the CLI.

Comment: `$table->id();` how are you doing this?? if you migrate you must get an error like bad method exception id.

Comment: No I don't have any problems when I migrate :/

Comment: which version of laravel are you using?? this must gives you error. however if not does it make id the pk of the table?

Comment: I'm using 7.2.1 Laravel Framwork...

Comment: I suspect there is a problem with the naming convention (camel case, snake format,...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a reference ID like

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('modality_id');
```

is not sufficient.
You should also add a foreign key:

```
$table->foreign('modality_id')->references('id')->on('modalities');
```

https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints

Comment: Thank you ! But the modality <-> reportsGroup linkage is working very well without ! It is the relationships with the Report Model that doesn't work ...

Comment: hum ok, maybe foreign is not neccessary.
anyhow having closer look following seems not ok:

in Modality.php, return is missing in reportGroups function
reportGroups name is not consistent with other name, should be reportsGroups

In function reports in ReportsGroup.php, you need to specify index name 'reportsGroup_id' as well, otherwise it will look for reports_group_id

Comment: Thanks you Julien ! How can I specify index name ?

Comment: Exactly as you did in Reports.php:
`public function reports()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Report::class, 'reportsGroup_id');
    }`

Comment: This (plus correcting a few code mistake) fixed everything ! Thanks you all !